# Jimmy Bogard: "Ajax is used very, very sparingly." Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, user-interface

I have seen a lot of references to how Jimmy Bogard and his team do web sites.  One of the things in [his article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) about how they do view models, is that they use Ajax "very, very sparingly."  But I don't really see him go into details as to why -- or what they do instead.

To me, Ajax -- when done well -- is what makes the user experience on a web site super fluid and seamless.  I understand that the user shouldn't have to wait much, if at all, for Ajax to respond to methods.  But he makes it sound as if it should be avoided, if possible, at all costs.

Can someone help me understand the smells of using Ajax, and the alternatives that should be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this post is out of date (2009). Today half of the internet is AJAX. See google, facebook, twitter, stackoverflow, and all the "web applications".

Maybe in 2009 it was not a good practice because:

- **IE6**
- slow browsers
- search engine robots didn't used AJAX.
- the users were not ready to AJAX.
- standard and cross browser issues
- XML and JSON were not a wide range accepted thing.

Today there is good frameworks which helps you for better ajax web applications (jQuery). If a web developer team searches for an employee, the criterium is HTML5, AJAX minimum. So dont afraid of ajax.

Answer (score 8):

The complete quote from the article is:

> AJAX is used very, very sparingly.  Section 508 compliance is required

That is the only mention of AJAX in that entire article, and it is in conjunction with Section 508 reference.

Section 508 is about accessibility to people with disabilities.  So, for example, if you use a screen reader, it will read what's visible on the screen, and nuances such as on-hovers and stuff may not be "accessible".

I do not take "AJAX sparingly" in that article as anything more general than its (implied) interference with accessibility.

Answer (score 5):

I think much of the blowback against AJAX, particularly early on, was the tendency to use it for EVERYTHING. Standard browser behavior be damned. So, in the mind of many developers, AJAX meant breaking user expectations just to be "hip" or something. However, I think it has matured to a stable, powerful and well-accepted method now to save user states, settings, filters, or basically anything that doesn't warrant a full page refresh.

Comment: concur.. whenever a new tech gets hot people must be seen to be "flossing" it :)

Comment: Aye a whole raft of questions on how to stop a user hitting the back thinking it was going go back. Damned irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit the nail on the head in your statement "when done well".  Design the site for HTML only and then use JavaScript to improve the UI for the majority of people that do have it enabled.  Give the people that have the newest browsers the best experience of all.  With the modern JS frameworks, the development overhead shouldn't really be noticable!  There are  many instances where a dependency on Javascript is introduced that is not even needed and in some cases actually ruins the user experience.   Javascript/Ajax doesn't define a good UI, but it can ruin one.